# How do I check which merge tool I use?

Tags: git, mergetool

I want to check which merge tool my git is set to - I just don't remember the name. I know I can wait till the next merge opportunity to run it via `git merge tool` and see what was it, but I'd like to type something like `git mergetool status` to see what is the tool (and what is the version, for instance).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to see what git resolves as the difftool, over the different config files:

```
git config --get merge.tool
```

If the result is not a builtin, then to see how it is configured:

```
git config --get mergetool.THE_MERGE_TOOL
```

see git help config

Comment: first gives nothing, second: `error: invalid key: mergetool.THE_MERGE_TOOL`

Comment: I had previously set it to kdiff3 with `git config merge.tool kdiff3` and `git config --get merge.tool` returned `kdiff3`. I was hoping git would be able to test-launch kdiff3

Comment: Mine seems to be working correctly: >git config --get merge.tool
unityyamlmerge is my output and unityyamlmerge is the tool I had it set to. I am guessing if you have empty output perhaps you do not have any merge tool set. I had to use git config to set my merge tool manually.

Answer (score 8):

Check your configurations:

`git config --list`

Look for the `merge.tool` configuration variable.

Comment: have only `user.name`, `user.email`

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in your git config file:
project local config file is at: `.git/config`
global config file is at:`/home/user/.gitconfig`(only for linux and mac os)
what config file looks like:

```
[user]
   name = name
   email = name@gmail.com
[color]
   ui = auto
[mergetool "[tool]"]
   cmd = vimdiff
```

You can use `git mergetool --tool-help` to show avilable merge tools. like this:

```
 'git mergetool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
    emerge
    gvimdiff
    gvimdiff2
    gvimdiff3
    vimdiff
    vimdiff2
    vimdiff3
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Git configuration file (typically located at `~/.gitconfig`), there is a section prefixed with `[mergetool]`. e.g.:

```
[mergetool "[tool]"]
    cmd = opendiff
```

The `cmd` tells you (and--more importantly--git itself) what command to use for mergetool. In my case, it's opendiff.

Knowing this, you can view the man pages for your tool to determine what its version number is.